# Why is FireFox v65.0 Debugger not showing the same content as seen in the browser area?

Tags: debugging, firefox

I'm testing to see if my web-site, which is hosted on a remote web-server, works in FireFox Quantum v65.0 64bit.  I see that while the myVideos page displays properly in the browser, when I click one of the buttons on this page, nothing happens, which is odd, since in Chrome, IE, and Edge, this button works properly.
In the Console, I see:

ReferenceError: event is not defined [Learn More] myVideos:3156:2

```
addVideoRow http://web-site/.../myVideos:3156
onclick http://web-site/.../myVideos:1
```

Where http://web-site/.../myVideos represents the actual page with in my web-site that I'm testing.

Looking at the page source in the debugger's (index) tab, I see that the source code ends at line 967 -- no where near the 3156 line in the console error message!  After looking more closely at the source cod, I find that the code isn't the right code for the myVideos page.  Rather, it is the source code for my site's home page, yet the debugger's Sources pane clearly says that I'm looking at the myVideos page.  Understand that the home page is completely different than the myVideo page, and it doesn't contain the addVideoRow function, yet the error I'm getting isn't that the function doesn't exist, but that event within the function isn't defined.

Also note that in order to get to the myVideos page, I have to navigate through several preceding pages.  So I again open each of these in the debugger to see if they load correctly, and each one shows the right page code in the code tab, and the links and buttons that I click in the browser pane to navigate between the pages all work properly.

Next I close the (index) tab and try opening the myVideos page using Ctrl-P, type **myVideos** into the search field, and select '(index) /app_dev.php/Board/myVideos', but my site's home page was displays again.

I would have tried opening the file using Ctrl-Shift-F, but my site's files all reside on a remote web-server, and I don't know how to specify the necessary path to those files.

How do I get FireFox to open the right page in the debugger so that I can trace the execution when I click the button that produces the ReferenceError, so that I can fix the error?

Is this an intermittent issue in FireFox v65.0, and should I drop-back to a previous version?

Comment: I ran the page in the developer version of Firefox, and it ran fine.  So now I need to know what to do when it works in the developer version,  but appears to load the wrong page into the debugger of the standard version.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue regarding Firefox debugger showing the source code of my index page instead of the real page.  Have you found the cause?

Comment: Sorry, no.  My guess is they, "the developers at FireFox", are quietly de-supporting the version of FireFox that's having the problem that we're encountering in favor of the newer version that is represented by the developer version.  That's why so may months have go by with an unanswered bug report.